# How to I make specific section function run and go back to the main loop?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I am currently making a small car simulation program. I have to make the car(a single character) move within the array. Let's say, I have a function that has 3 moves.

```
void Move_around(){
      //first move
      Car.x++;
      //second move
      Car.y++;
      //3rd move
      Car.x++;
}
```

I want the car to only move once in the main loop. So once the first move is done, it goes back to the main loop then goes back to the function() and does the second move and so on. How should I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by *main loop*?

Comment: @MartinZhai It is a loop that is in main. It is basically the loop that makes the car move every one second. I don't want it to move 3 spaces in one second which in my case it does.

Comment: You can have only one line of `Car.x++;` in your `Move_around()`, so it makes only one move on your call. Then call it in main loop.

Comment: But by doing so I'm not "moving around" and it did not achieve the purpose of moving around.

Comment: @MartinZhai My question already had the complete explanation. There's no need for me to show all of my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few possible options:

1. Split the function in three small ones and call them in order from the main loop.
2. Use coroutines.
3. Turn coordinate changes into events and put them in the event queue. This time, the function itself merely takes an event from the queue and processes it.

You can combine 1. and 3. by using small functions as events in the queue.